# Ble discover service from device

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

A simple question. Is it possible to discover services from a device in BLE without connecting to this device (`mConnectedGatt = device.connectGatt(this, false, mGattCallback);`)  ?.

Answer (score 0):

Found it, startLeScan can take UUID[] as first param :
`public boolean startLeScan (UUID[] serviceUuids, BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback callback);`